# Implementing USB sharing over network

Tags: android, sockets, usb, adb

I set out to see if I can configure my development environment such that I can run `adb` commands from my dev box in the office network on an Android device that is connected to the USB port of my laptop which is in the same LAN (or connected via VPN). I specifically wanted the adb server to be running on the dev box and communicating to the adb daemon on my device over the network. I didn't want to connect the adb client that runs on the dev box to the adb server running on my laptop which the adb tool allows via its `-H` option and I didn't want to use the `adb connect` or `adb tcpip` commands. Basically, I just wanted to relay the adb communication that happens over the USB cable to happen over the network (SSH tunnel).

As a proof of concept, I managed to build a prototype using a [third party solution](http://www.eltima.com/products/usb-over-ethernet/) that would allow me to share USB over network but now I want to see if I can build the same solution using port forwarding and some coding. However, my technical knowledge of USB drivers, OS kernels, and how the USB communication works (on Linux and Mac) is very basic so I am hoping to find some answers from the community.

**Question:** Where in the USB stack do I need to start creating hooks so I can forward all data communication of a certain USB port to a different process running in the same OS?

**Proposal:** If I can find the port numbers that the USB drivers on each machine communicate to the process in the kernels that then forwards the data to the application, I can use port forwarding on each machine to re-route the communication to a daemon process running on each machine that then wraps the data in TCP/IP and transfers over the network. The image below depicts this scenario:

[image]

The adb server that runs on the client machine will need to be configured to route its communication to a port on the client machine that an damon emulator process listens. This daemon process will then have to transmit the data over the network to another daemon process running on the server machine that hosts the Android device via a USB port. The latter daemon process listening to the same port that the client machine send out TCP/IP data will then read the data, transforms it to adb protocol, and sends the data to the USB device. The parts of this solution that I am trying to learn more about is how to write a daemon process that acts as a USB device emulator. Any help or recommendations for further reading is appreciated.

Comment: The [usbip project](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) is another solution for transporting USB over TCP/IP. I am curious why ADB's existing networking support is insufficient for your use.

Comment: There is no significant reason other than wanting to use the version of adb that runs on my development machine instead of the one that runs on my Mac laptop. Same exact experience but slightly closer to how things normally run when I directly work on the development machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy fix to this problem. I was able to get this working by running the commands below.

On my remote development machine: (`$remote_host`)

```
adb kill-server
```

On my laptop:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
ssh -N -R 5307:localhost:5307 $remote_host
```

And, finally on my remote development:

```
adb start-server
```

I was then able to run `adb devices` on my remote machine (using an SSH tunnel) and see the SN of the device that is connected to my laptop.

Comment: I like your solution. It would have worked for me, but I don't have the same versions of adb on macOS (1.0.41) and Ubuntu (1.0.39). One suggestion. I believe your solution was intended for the default adb port but you've swapped the middle two digits of the port numbers. It should be `ssh -N -R 5037:localhost:5037 $remote_host`